# Flutter: strange bug in row with aligment spaceEvenly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my app, I often use conditional widget visibility to hide or display a widget. It works fine but recently, the design was not as expected as you can see in below images.
[image]
[image]

All Chips are laid in a `Row` with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`. When there are 5 buttons, the design is ok, but with 4 buttons (the middle one is hidden), a additional space  appears in the middle, which is not perfect.

Here the code

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const Icon(
              Icons.school,
            ),
            onPressed: () {...         
            },
          ),
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const ImageIcon(
              AssetImage("assets/images/Intervention.png"),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ...
            },
          ),
          deviceId != -1
              ? ActionChip(
                  backgroundColor:
                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  shape: const CircleBorder(),
                  label: const ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/images/History.png"),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    ...
                  },
                )
              : const SizedBox(
                ),
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const Icon(
              Icons.save_alt,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ...
            },
          ),
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const Icon(
              Icons.settings,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
             ...
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I tried to put the middle button in a `Visibility widget`, but the result was the same.
How to solve this ugly problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `SizedBox` it actually take invisible space in that row so row consider it as an item and put padding around it because of `spaceEvenly` setting. Instead of put `SizedBox` in `else` condition, you can use `if` and set nothing for else condition, like this:

```
 Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const Icon(
              Icons.school,
            ),
            onPressed: () {...         
            },
          ),
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const ImageIcon(
              AssetImage("assets/images/Intervention.png"),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ...
            },
          ),
          if(deviceId != -1) //<--- add this
              ActionChip(
                  backgroundColor:
                      Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  shape: const CircleBorder(),
                  label: const ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage("assets/images/History.png"),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    ...
                  },
                ),
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const Icon(
              Icons.save_alt,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              ...
            },
          ),
          ActionChip(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            label: const Icon(
              Icons.settings,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
             ...
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

**Result**: top row is for using `if` the second row is for not using it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this way to do, I always use ternary condition like in React Native, and in 99% of cases, it works